# Incompressible Navier-Stokes equation with heat conduction

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-pde, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

How does the incompressible Navier-Stokes system read with heat conduction?
Where can I find an existence result for its weak solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an extensive literature, this could be helpful entry point:  
[Solving Navier-Stokes equations coupled with a heat transfer equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00820) (2015)

> In this paper, the dynamics of an incompressible fluid in a bounded
>   connected domain, described by Navier-Stokes equations coupled with a
>   heat transfer equation, is investigated by a method inspired from the
>   non-commutative strategy developed by Bagarello.The solution of
>   systems of partial differential equations is derived with the help of
>   the unbounded self-adjoint densely defined Hamiltonian operator of the
>   physical model and the Hankel transform.

Weak solutions have been studied in [On the existence of global weak solutions to the Navier–Stokes equations for viscous compressible and heat conducting fluids](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82480680.pdf) (2007). (This paper focuses on compressible flow, but also discusses the literature for incompressible flow.)

Comment: Thank you. It has been pointed out to me that the Navier-Stokes system with heat is actually called "Navier-Stokes-Fourier" system. I'm confused by the different notations and formulations of the problem across papers. Could you possibly write it down?